# Kubernetes: how to assign cpus according to memory?

Tags: kubernetes

For example:

A node has 48Cores/64G(2 numa node, 24Cores/32G per numa node).

Pod `P1` needs 12Cores/32G, Pod `P2` needs 12Cores/16G.

By default, the `CPUManager` will pack CPUs onto one NUMA node until it is filled, so the two pods will be on the same numa node.

But what I desire is that when `P1` is assigned to CPUs on numa node 0, `P2` should be assigned to CPUs on numa node 1, because there is none memory left on numa node 0.

Does k8s support this policy?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a k8s cluster the kube-scheduker will naturally schedule the next pod directly on the node where there are enough resources, it is mentioned in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/#:%7E:text=The%20Kubernetes%20scheduler%20is%20a,Pod%20to%20a%20suitable%20Node.) as well.

> The Kubernetes scheduler is a control plane process which assigns Pods
> to Nodes. The scheduler determines which Nodes are valid placements
> for each Pod in the scheduling queue according to constraints and
> available resources. The scheduler then ranks each valid Node and
> binds the Pod to a suitable Node.

Comment: The `Node` in the official documentation is k8s concept which means a worker machine. What I mean is the `NUMA node`management policy inside a `Node`(worker machine)

Comment: @HypoGump I think Numa-aware memory manager might be useful in this case. Please go through this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/memory-manager/) for more information

Comment: @HypoGump is your issue resolved revert back if you are facing the issues...

Comment: The MemoryManager seems to have a slight gap in functionality from what I'm looking for. What I actually want is a `memory-aware CPU allocation algorithm` that prioritizes assigning CPUs on numa nodes with available memory.

Comment: @HypoGump there is another kubernetes plugin called **`TopologyManager`**, using this  you can apply policies while deploying your pod, go through [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/01/kubernetes-1-18-feature-topoloy-manager-beta/) for more information.

Comment: @HypoGump is your issue resolved revert back if you need any additional information.